# Cannot run jupyter notebook by python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

MacBook laptop

Have activated py27 in the terminal. When I tried to run `jupyter notebook`, it returned:

```
bash-3.2$ source activate py27
(py27) bash-3.2$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 15, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 17, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
  File "/Users/xx/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 162
    print('Error in generated code:', file=sys.stderr)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(py27) bash-3.2$
```

How to solve this? Is it impossible to run python 2.7 in Jupyter right now?

Comment: Same here. It looks like conda pulled in py3 version of some dependencies.

Comment: I found this workaround:
```conda install decorator=4.4.0```

Comment: Got the same error with Ubuntu Linux and a recent Mac with M1 processor.
python version 2.7.18 and tried almost every version of the jupyter package available.
But Claudio's workaround fixed it!

Comment: Another package that turned out to be necessary:
`conda install functools_lru_cache`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

```
    from decorator import decorator
  File "/home/hamza/miniconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 162
    print('Error in generated code:', file=sys.stderr)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found that the installed "decorator" version (in my case decorator-5.1.0, i guess it was automatically installed with jupyter by conda) requires a Python>=3.5, while I had python 2.7.

all I did is reinstall decorator package to fit py27:

```
pip uninstall decorator
```

> Successfully uninstalled decorator-5.1.0

```
pip install decorator
```

> Successfully installed decorator-4.4.2